# SQL Server decimal values are not inserted correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to save decimal values having up to 14 digits precision (Decimal(20,14)). Howover, if the inserted value have less precision digits, the missing digits are completed randomely, rather than just adding zeros. For example the value 382.593375 is saved as 382.59337499999998. Similarly 381.949875 is saved as 381.94987500000002.

I tried to use the data type float instead of decimal, but the saved values can not go up to 14 precision decimals. Any help ?

Comment: Show example code reproducing the issue. SQL Server isn't doing this on its own. There is something wrong with how you are handling the data - probably converting it to `float` and then `decimal`

Comment: This sounds like you are paying a `float` to SQL Server and `INSERT`ing it into a `decimal`; as such the problem is your choice of data type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your choice of data types, *not* SQL Server. This issue can be reproduced with the following:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(20,14),CONVERT(float,382.593375));
```

This returns the value `382.59337499999998`. This is not surprising because base 2 values (which a `float` is) cannot store non-integer base 10 values accurately. As such when the value is converted *back* to a base 10 value (`decimal(20,14)` in this case) the accuracy of the `float` is used.

The solution? In what ever process you are defining your input parameter, ensure you define the value to be a base 10 data type; then you don't get rounding issues.